# H.264 (AMD VCE) encoder for HandBrake

Tags: 18.04, handbrake

I'm using HandBrake version 1.2.2 but I cannot find options to use the Video encode option **H.264 (AMD VCE)**

What are the required steps to be able to use AMD ACE on HandBrake?

Comment: If you have suitable hardware you should see the option in preferences under the video tab. Details here: https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/latest/technical/video-vce.html

Comment: what if you are using handbrake-cli?